# What is createSecretKey for in nodejs crypto module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, hmac

Im trying to figure out why should I use `createSecretKey` in crypto module instead of string.

What difference between this:

```js
const secret = crypto.createSecretKey('mysupersecret'); // Creates SecretKeyObject

hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
hash = hmac.update('somemessage').digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

and this:

```js
const secret = 'mysupersecret'; // just string

hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
hash = hmac.update('somemessage').digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

Both output: `81a86a988a751d4523ebc1ccb3150b094ef7d51a0fbe111600d1832c6de68f9f`

Does `SecretKeyObject` provides any benefits?
Using `createSecretKey` improves security of my code?

Comment: online doc,   "Most applications should consider using the new KeyObject API instead of passing keys as strings or Buffers due to improved security features." https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-keyobject

Comment: Yes. But it's no clarification about what "improved security features" means.

Comment: we'll need to look at the KeyObject secret data field to see whether it's encrypted or obfuscated in some way instead of just a text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createSecretKey` adds additional security benefits by returning an instance of the `KeyObject` class.

From the documentation [https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#:~:text=Class%3A-,KeyObject,-%23](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#:%7E:text=Class%3A-,KeyObject,-%23)

> Node.js uses a KeyObject class to represent a symmetric or asymmetric
> key, and each kind of key exposes different functions. The
> crypto.createSecretKey() ...  KeyObject objects are not to be created
> directly using the new keyword.

One example is of a benefit of using the KeyObject class:

- Automatically zeroed out (deleted and replaced with zeros) when no longer needed. Stops accidental leaks. If you use a secret key it would be stored in memory until out of scope. Which means it could potentially expose the key to other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I benchmarked it and using a KeyObject created with createSecretKey is faster. Nodejs prefers the KeyObject.